# Excess white space, page width

Tags: html, css, width, stylesheet

New here, do let me know if I've posted in wrong place.

I'm making a new website, bit of a hobby, self thought with help of online forums and Google :)

Problem I have is, I've not used much CSS before, but appears this is the best way to style. While visiting a page on a mobile, it seams to be zoomed right out, and have a huge white space down the right hand side. I've looked into several posts online, but cannot seam to get rid of this excess space.

Here is the first part of the file to display this..

```
    <style type="text/css">
html, body {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
    posistion: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    width:80%;
    background:#ddd;
    padding: 0% 0%;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

    #menu {
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 15px;
       margin-left: 15px;
        width:1.4em;
        display: block;
        background:#ddd;
        font-size:1.35em;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    #nav {
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 44px;
       margin-left: 15px;
        width: 135px;
        display: block;
        background:#ddd;
        font-size:1.35em;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    #nav.js {
        display: none;
    }

    ul {
       margin-left: 0px;
        width:150px;
        list-style: none;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    li {
        margin-left: 0px;
        width:auto;
        border-right:none;
        z-index:1000;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Create a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/) for better understanding of your problem

Comment: Thanks, will look into that :)

Comment: Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Just like @agursky mentioned, please post the HTML. As for your CSS: Is the "main" element a class or id? The `position` property in "main" is misspelled. In `li a` you have `padding: 0% 0%;` It should be `padding: 0`. In `#menu` the `em` in `width:1.4em` should be reserved for sizing fonts, not block level elements. If you want relative widths with block level elements use `%` for starters. Hope that will help some.

Comment: Thank you for replies. Will have to ensure spelling in future, and for next time will definitely consider a fiddle and ensuring I post the full html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most browsers resize the page to fit but you can prevent that by using the **META** tag like this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, did just the job, need to now rethink sizing of items as they are 400px, bigger than many mobile screens. Will use the trusty % as before.